# Schools Pupils' Reports or without apostrophe?

Tags: apostrophe

Not finding a solid answer on google.

This title:

> Schools Pupils' Reports to Parents
>
> School's Pupils' Reports to Parents

Which one is correct?

Comment: Please see also [ell.se] There are also some related previous posts on this site.

Comment: Do you have any examples @Kris? Not seen an exmaple to cover this double potential 's

Comment: I would say _school's pupil reports_ myself. They are from (of) the school, they are each about an individual pupil and they are in the plural.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/280530/14666 might be of some help.

Comment: Both are horrible. If this is a title “School Reports” will do. If this is text “School reports to Parents” will avoid the possessive and “pupils” is superfluous — who else would the report be about. Never let yourself be trapped between unsatisfactory alternatives in English. Always restructure and simplify. (Which would you prefer, the gallows or the electric chair?)

Comment: Why does the report belong to the pupils?

Answer (score 1):

There is no grammar rule against consecutive possessives; saying something like `Mary's dog's bed's pillow's color matches my shirt` is grammatically acceptable. It is, however, a stylistic issue as it doesn't read very well (`My shirt matches the color of the pillow on the bed Mary's dog sleeps on` is still a bit unwieldy but definitely better).

In other words, `school's` would imply that there's only one school whereas `schools` is just wrong. If there are multiple schools, you should write `schools'`. Regular punctuation rules.

That said, I wouldn't use either as a title. It's confusing at best. If the report in question is by the pupils, then it should just be `(School) Pupils' Reports to Parents`.