# Possessive apostrophe-s on three nouns in a row

Tags: grammar, possessives

I just read [Two possessive nouns in a row](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280530/two-possessive-nouns-in-a-row), but am still trying to wrap my head around possessive apostrophe-s in English, specifically, I am trying to say something along the following lines:

"The American news outlets' CNN's and Fox News' coverage of the election" ('s on all possessive nouns)

or should it be

"The American news outlets CNN and Fox News' coverage of the election" ('s on the last possessive noun)

or

"The American news outlets' CNN and Fox News coverage of the election" ('s only at the first possessive noun)

Comment: News isn't a posessive noun, it isn't even a plural. It's a mass noun that ends in an 's'. In fact it is a very specific noun that doesn't really really have a singlular form. For instance no one would say "I have a new for you".

Comment: If it was me I wouldn't even try to use the posessive. I'd just go with "The coverage of the election by CNN and Fox News..:"

Comment: Peter's, Paul's, and Mary's costumes reflected the theme of the concert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to just reword, rather than trying to make complex constructs fit an awkward pattern.

> The election coverage of the American news outlets CNN and Fox News